# Concatenating columns to one in ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy

I have this dictionary:

```
dict1 = ({'ROADS' : ['STREETNAME', 'LEFTFROM', 'LEFTTO', 'RIGHTFROM', 'RIGHTTO'],
            'ITA' :  ['I.ID_BOUND', 'I.BOUND_IDQ']})
```

I want for every file(ROADS,ITA) to concatenate its columns to one column.

**Example:**

For the first file concatenate: `'STREETNAME', 'LEFTFROM', 'LEFTTO', 'RIGHTFROM', 'RIGHTTO'` to one column in a loop so it can happen for all the other files in the dictionary with their related columns.

I have done this in geopandas but I am having trouble with doing this to Arcpy.

```
In geopandas:

for k, v in dict2.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v))
    df.columns = v                 # as v are the columns in the dictionary
    df['new'] = df.astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1) #new field with the concat columns
```

I would like this in ArcPy only.

I tried:

```
In ArcPy:

for k,v in dict1.items():
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(k, v) as cur:
        for row in cur:
            row[2] = row[0] + row[1] #<-should work for all number of columns a file has
            ucur.updateRow(row)
```

To see how the result should look like:

**Example:**
if the file has 3 columns a,b,c it will be

from this:

```
a  b c
1 js 1
1 hd 1
1 jd 1
```

to this:

```
a  b c  new
1 js 1  1js1
1 hd 1  1hd1
1 jd 1  1jd1
```

**Update**
From BERA's answer:

```
for k,v in dict2.items():
    arcpy.AddField_management(k,'concat','LONG')
    field_to_update = ['concat']
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(k,v+field_to_update) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[-1] = ''.join([str(i) for i in row[:-1] if i is not None])
```

It makes all the rows NULL. Probably a problem with the concatenation of numbers in the columns?
Also is 'LONG' as type correct for the new field?

Comment: Your code just clobbers the contents of the first and third columns with the content of the second. You only need one pass, with `row[3] = row[0]+row[1]+row[2]`, with the appropriate column names specified as an array in the UpdateCursor.

Comment: isn't there a more clean way like : `newcol = [Field Name] & " " & [Field Name] & " " & [Field Name]`?

Comment: To Vince’s answer, I will also add that in python you can only concatenate strings type with same type of variable. So you should write: row[3]=str(row[0])+row[1]+str(row[2]).

Comment: Can someone write a full answer so I can get what you mean?

Comment: @RaskarKapak What if it is not known what type the column is, like in the loop here that has many types of column in each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use join with list comprehension:

```
a = [1,'Hello',None,2]
''.join([str(i) for i in a if i is not None])

'1Hello2'
```

Will work with the updatecursor since it is returning a list for each row:

```
import arcpy
fields = ['Field1','Field2','Field3'] #Can be any length
field_to_update = ['Field99']
fc = r'C:\data.gdb\featureclass'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields+field_to_update) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[-1] = ''.join([str(i) for i in row[:-1] if i is not None])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: it makes the rows NULL of the new field. Can you check the update in my question to see what I did?Thanks

Comment: why does it make null values?

Comment: just made a post about it I have tried text as well.And nothing. See the question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301698/concatenation-gives-null-values-in-arcpy

Comment: I have provided in the question the code as it is.

Comment: I have tried `arcpy.AddField_management(k,'concat','TEXT')` and gives NULL too.

Comment: @user51332 sry I forgot the updateRow line, try again!